# Function crashing because of so many iterations jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have a page with approximately 300 `div`'s on, I toggle their css so they're either 100% wide or say 200 pixels. My function worked find when there was only 10 or so divs, but now there's so many, my function seems to crash.

Can anybody explain why this happens or 'enhance' my current function?

```
$('.grid').click(function () {
            $('.vacancy').animate({ opacity: 0 }, 500, function () {
                $(".vacancy").switchClass("listview", "gridview", 100);
                $(".vacancy").stop().animate({ opacity: 1 }, 500);
                $('a.gridView').removeClass('grid-active');
                $('a.listView').addClass('list-active');
            });
            return false;
});

$('.list').click(function () {
            $('.vacancy').animate({ opacity: 0 }, 500, function () {
                $(".vacancy").switchClass("gridview", "listview", 100);
                $(".vacancy").stop().animate({ opacity: 1 }, 500);
                $('a.gridView').removeClass('grid-active');
                $('a.listView').addClass('list-active');
            });
            return false;
});
```

Comment: Can you post your html and css too? Maybe a jsfiddle?

Comment: Usually when I encountering jQuery performance issues I fallback to native javascript. Maybe you can queue your animations to run them all at once?

Comment: Yes a fiddle would be much easier to troubleshoot with. Also, jQuery animations are relatively heavy on the browser. Have you considered CSS animations?

Answer (score 0):

The callback function fires for each element animated.

If you have 300 `.vacancy` divs, The callback will execute 300 times. Each time the callback executes, `$(".vacancy").switchClass()` will be called for 300 elements. 300 x 300 is... a lot.

You can start by using `this` in the callback:

```
$('.grid').click(function () {
        $('.vacancy').animate({ opacity: 0 }, 500, function () {
            $(this).switchClass("listview", "gridview", 100);
            $(this).stop().animate({ opacity: 1 }, 500);
            $('a.gridView').removeClass('grid-active');
            $('a.listView').addClass('list-active');
        });
        return false;
});
```

You'll need some other method to reduce the number of times the other two lines are called, but without the html, I can't say what the solution would be.

---

Here's a fiddle with a demonstration: http://jsfiddle.net/jkcY3/

```
$.fn.logMe = function() {
    return this.each(function() {
        console.log('logMe called', this); 
    });
};

$('.vacancy').animate({ opacity: 0 }, 500, function() {
   $('.vacancy').logMe();
});
```

If I had 300 divs, I'd get 90000 calls to `logMe()`;